# Where is the Tumblr API Key?

Tags: tumblr

Their documentation is not clear at all

[image]

There is nothing at all anywhere on the site labeled as the "API Key" but there is

- consumer_key:
- consumer_secret:
- token:
- token_secret:

Comment: Your API key is your consumer key.

Comment: They mentioned it in the [Authentication section](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the consumer_key and consumer_secret after registering a new app at Tumblr [here](https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps) (it is called *OAuth Consumer Key* and there is a link below to get the Secret key of the app).

The token and token_secret keys are generated after allowing access of an app to a Tumblr account. They will be returned as parameters after returning to the callback script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already registered your app and are looking for your keys you can find it at - https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps , it will be a list of your apps with their consumer keys and a toggle to reveal their secret keys.